# Python re.sub not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have this HTML

```
b>Source: </b> <a href=\'http: //website.com/ml/datasets/Iris\'>text here</a><br><p class="normal">Creator: R.A. Fisher
<br><br>Donor: Namehere <b>\'@\'</b> website.com</u>)</p>
```

I want to remove multiple `<br>` from this using Regex

I am using this `_str = re.sub('<br>\s*','<br>',_str)`

But it returns string as it was, with no change at all.

If I use same regex but specify a different replacing character then it works, this `_str = re.sub('<br>\s*','',_str)`

Comment: Your regexp means "Replace `<br>` tags optionally followed by whitespace with `<br>`". It doesn't contain any notion of "multiple `<br>`". Effectively, your regexp replaces all instances of `<br>` with `<br>`, so you obviously do not see a difference.

Comment: sorry I didnt get you @VincentSavard ... I want to replace multiple existince of <br> with one <br> ...

Comment: I understand what you want. What I am telling you is that isn't what you wrote. You need to fix your regexp first.

Comment: Can you please tell me correct regex? I will accept as answer

Comment: @VincentSavard what will be `notion of "multiple <br>` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only stripping off spaces following `<br>` with that. You can instead use a *positive lookahead* to remove all `<br>`s that have another `<br>` immediately following:

```
re.sub(r'<br>(?=<br>)', '', _str)
```

You may handle inter `<br>` spaces with:

```
re.sub(r'<br>(?=\s*<br>)', '', _str)
```

Comment: Accepted, a little explanation of regex working would be great ... thanks anyways

Comment: Here: [*positive lookahead assertion*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)